# Invalid object name (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have this error

> Invalid object name 'dbo.Vacancies'

But I have Model for Vacancies.

Here it is:

```
public partial class Vacancy
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Vacancy()
    {
        this.Interwiers = new HashSet<Interwier>();
        this.InvitationMails = new HashSet<InvitationMail>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Vacancy_Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Вакансия")]
    public string VacancyName { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> CompanyID { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Interwier> Interwiers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<InvitationMail> InvitationMails { get; set; }
}
```

}

Also I have table Vacancy.

This code I have in IdentityModels:

```
public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SmartSolutions.Models.Vacancy> Vacancies { get; set; }
```

Here is code of View where I try to show data from table.

```
// GET: VacanciesAll
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var vacancies = db.Vacancies.Include(v => v.Company);
    return View(vacancies.ToList());
}
```

Here is the Table:
[image]

Here is the table in EF
[image]
Why am I getting an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the Table exists in your Sql Database. Chances are it is not there in your Database, hence, the error.

[image]

If the table exists, make sure you are mapping your EF table to the correct table name in DbContext.

Comment: @E.S your table name is `Vacancy` or `Vacancies`. I think that is the problem. Your mapping is not correct in EF.

Comment: Vacancy , but I have this ` public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SmartSolutions.Models.Vacancy> Vacancies { get; set; }` so it must be all okay

Comment: Change it to `System.Data.Entity.DbSet<SmartSolutions.Models.Vacancy> Vacancy { get; set; }` and try. It needs to map the name of Object not the type.

Answer (score 1):

It could be loooking at the wrong database.

The DbContext class should match the name in the connection string.

Make sure your connection string "name" property is correct.

Example: PortalEntities DbContext should match PortalEntities in connectionStrings.

```
 public class PortalEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Delegate> Delegates { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Status> Statuses { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<PortalEntities>(null);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }

<connectionStrings>

    <add name="PortalEntities" connectionString="Data Source=serverName;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=dbName;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>

</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the EF Layers [ SSDL - CSDL - MSL ] 
this is conflict between your EF layers and database engine